# IntelliJ keeps moving cursor focus to the Build Output tool window while coding

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA CE, on macOS Monterey, and while coding it frequently builds the code base every few seconds, automatically.

This becomes very frustrating as then the cursor focus would move to the Build Output window while I'm writing my code, after every few seconds. The errors shown in the window are the obvious compile errors as I'm still writing my code.

I tried turning off "Build project automatically" and "Build project" in "Actions on Save" setting but that doesn't help. I'm not sure which setting is causing this problem.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-213.6461.79, built on December 28, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.13+7-b1751.21 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.1
```

Comment: Does it happens when build fails - as described here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168699?

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what is happening but with the Java compilation. I remember it doesn't use to happen with the earlier versions.

Comment: @AdityaAbinash have you managed to fix this behavior?

Comment: @shotex I never found a solution, but after I updated to the follow-up releases the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

When a build fails (i.e. the compiler generates 1+ errors), IntelliJ by default moves the curser to the first error.

This behaviour can be configured using the setting "Automatically show first error in editor".

[image: action search in IntelliJ with text 'automatically show first error in editor']

Comment: This workaround makes TDD possible again (albeit with a few shortcomings: e.g. the build error window is still opened, but no longer focused)

Comment: Is there a way to disable the opening of the build error windows? I'm debugging and it's annoying that intellij always jumps away from my debug window